# Как очистить (удалить) прорисовку

Tags: java, swing

в простых играх по их завершению, как правильно выскакивает окно, где есть кнопка "Начать заново" и соответственно по нажатию игра начинается заново. У меня крестики нолики, и для прорисовки поля я использую `paintComponent`, и там же, при нажатии на поле, у меня прорисовывается фигура (крестик или нолик), каким образом я могу по нажатии на кнопку стереть фигуры, дабы игра началась заново, подскажите пожалуйста логику, спасибо.

Comment: если кому-то интересен код - https://github.com/Zherikhov/TicTacToe

Comment: стереть вы не можете, нужно рисовать заново.

Answer (score 0):

Что если заново создать объект игры?
Тогда все начнется сначала, а прошлый объект (больше не используется), сам сотрется.
Хотя сказать что-то не видя кода, довольно сложно.

Comment: А что если не создавать заново объект игры, а просто сбросить состояние? Вообще же на подобные слишком общие вопросы отвечать не стоит - нужно просто закрыть вопрос.

Comment: @AK почему? я просто хочу немного понять логику, учусь и многого еще не понимаю, мне кажется это лучше чем просить за тебя что-то сделать, уверен можно это объяснить на простом примере

Comment: я прикреплял ранее ссылку на гит, просо вставлять сюда даже основные классы я думаю не целесообразно, проще просто открыть проект я думаю, поправьте меня, если я не прав.

Comment: решил помочь - получил минус

Comment: минус не я ставил, выровнил